# Get Activity Context from Lifecycle object

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, android-context, android-architecture-lifecycle

I have made my component Lifecycle-aware. I want to use activityContext in that component.

My question is: is there any way to use activityContext from the `Lifecycle` object?

Answer (score 3):

There is not a way to do this - among other reasons, the `LifeCycle` object might not be backed by an `Activity`, or even anything attached to an `Activity` (for example, [`ProcessLifecycleOwner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner), and components depending on `Lifecycle`s should be agnostic of what that lifecycle is.

Instead, you should have the code creating your component pass it an `Activity` context.